# Get path of Page Manager page

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite

Basically I have created a page and it shows up fine.

[image: example of panel page with path set]

When I do a `arg` or `current_path` on that page it shows as a 404 path, not the one defined in the page.

```
current_path() => error-404
$_GET[q] => error-404
arg() => array(0 => error-404)
```

Is there a function that returns the path/URL that is set in the Page?

Answer (score 0):

Node that `current_path()` returns the URL path of the current page, not the URL. So on the `http://www.example.com/latest-deals` page it will return just `latest-deals`.

If you need to convert that to an actual URL, use `url(current_path())`, which will return `/latest-deals`. Or `url(current_path(), array('absolute' => TRUE))` if you need the absolute URL.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Artem M.   
Having current path return just a path and then turn that in to a URL is not a problem.  It's getting the correct path back that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

`current_path()` will return the path of the panel page.

The problem I was having was that we are using panels layouts for 404 pages as well.   I had a missing file in the theme layer that was generating a 404 error and that was getting picked up and overriding current path for the page.